# Android Service does not update UI after running

Tags: android, service

I have an interesting issue that I have been trying to fix for over a week. Its on Android and involves a service running in the background to send a message on an app.

It is quite complex so I'll list the stages below:

1 - User enters message

2 - User selects 'send' button which launches the apps main service (ComService/START_STICKY) and activity (HomeScreen) hides the EditText box used for the message, replacing it with a TextView with the words 'Sending'

3 - Service spawns worker thread

4 - Service gets entered text off of activity and connects to server

5 - Service sends the message and then gets result from server

6 - Service disconnects from server

7 - Service updates activity to show sent message and shows the edit text 
box again, as well as hides the TextView with the 'Sending' word

The issue is with stage 7. It uses a handler and message to communicate with the activity, as well as a separate class which holds the state of all of the activities in the app (to check if the UI is ok to update), but I commented this out from the code and the issue still exists so it is not this. The current set up works completely fine when the debugger is attached without any issues (why there is no logcat) and on the odd occasion when closing the app down and starting it up again. The problem begins when the debugger is detached and the app closed (via recent apps) for over around 5 seconds. The service completed its job by sending the message, as the message is added to the database and the user on the other end gets it, it is only the updating of the UI that is a problem, everything else seems to work fine!

Before sending the message, the service also connects to the server if there are any unread messages to indicate to other users that the user just read it. It follows very similar steps as above but was commented out and the issue still stays the same.

Ill post the code for the relevant steps below:
Stage 2

```
// Starts service to communicate with the server to send a message
Intent service = new Intent(this, ComService.class);
service.putExtra(ComService.requestType, ComService.sendTextMessage);
startService(service);
```

Stage 3

```
// Run when the service is being created
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent newIntent, int flags, int startId)
{
    intent = newIntent;
    currentInstance = this;

    // Launches processing thread
    ServiceHelper serviceHelper = new ServiceHelper(newIntent, this);
    serviceHelper.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Stage 4/5/6/7

```
// Sends a message with only text content
public void startText()
{
    // Initialises the class holding activity data
    StateManager sm = new StateManager(context);

    // Gets the data ready to be sent
    if(sm.getHomeScreen())
    {
        // Friend id and time
        friendId = HomeScreen.getFriendId();

        // Gets the message text
        messageTextContent = HomeScreen.getTextMessage(); // STAGE 4
    }
    else
    {
        allGood = false;
    }

    try
    {
        // Checks if any errors
        if(allGood)
        {
            // Checks if message to be sent is blank
            if(!messageTextContent.equals("") & messageTextContent.equals(" ") & !(messageTextContent == "") & !(messageTextContent == " "))
            {
                // Connects
                (sh.new Utility()).connect(); // STAGE 4

                // Checks if logged in
                if((sh.new CheckLogin()).start())
                {
                    // Sends request
                    sh.getNetwork().sendData(ServiceHelper.sendMessageTextRequest);

                    // Sends the friend id who message is addressed to
                    sh.getNetwork().sendData(friendId);

                    // Gets message date
                    messageDate = sh.getNetwork().getDataAsString();

                    // Sends the message type
                    sh.getNetwork().sendData(textType);

                    // Sends the message text
                    sh.getNetwork().sendData(messageTextContent); // STAGE 5

                    // Gets the message number
                    messageNumber = Integer.parseInt(sh.getNetwork().getDataAsString());

                    // Gets result and check if successful
                    String result = sh.getNetwork().getDataAsString(); // STAGE 5
                    if(!result.equals(ServiceHelper.requestSuccessful))
                    {
                        // Not successful
                        allGood = false;
                        errorMessage = result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Successful and saves data to database
                        addDatabaseTextMessage();
                    }

                    // Sends received indicator
sh.getNetwork().sendData(ServiceHelper.receivedIndicator);

                }
                else
                {
                    allGood = false;
                    errorMessage = tryAgainMsg;
                }

                // Closes connection
                (sh.new Utility()).finishConnection(); // STAGE 6

                // Gets current friend record
                UserDatabase db = new UserDatabase(context);
                FriendRecord fr = db.getFriendRecord(Integer.parseInt(friendId));

                // Increments message numbers by one and updates database
                fr.setTotalExchanged(fr.getTotalExchanged() + 1);
                db.updateFriendRecord(fr);
            }
            else
            {
                allGood = false;
                errorMessage = msgBlank;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            allGood = false;
            errorMessage = tryAgainMsg;
        }
    } catch(IOException e)
    {
        allGood = false;
        errorMessage = checkConnectionMsg;

        // Adds to log cat
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    } catch(Exception e2)
    {
        allGood = false;
        errorMessage = tryAgainMsg;

        // Adds to log cat
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e2.getMessage());
    }

    // Decides on result
    if(allGood)
    {
        // Refreshes the ui
        if(sm.getHomeScreen())  // STAGE 6
        {
            Message msg = HomeScreen.homeScreenInterface.obtainMessage(HomeScreen.sendSuccess); // STAGE 7
            HomeScreen.homeScreenInterface.sendMessage(msg); // STAGE 7
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Indicates error on ui
        if(sm.getHomeScreen())
        {
            Message msg = HomeScreen.homeScreenInterface.obtainMessage(HomeScreen.messageSendError); // STAGE 7
            msg.obj = errorMessage; // STAGE 6
            HomeScreen.homeScreenInterface.sendMessage(msg); // STAGE 7
        }
    }
}
```

State 7 (updating UI)

```
// Deals with service responses
public static Handler homeScreenInterface = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch(msg.what)
        {
...
...
           case HomeScreen.sendSuccess:
            // Enables and clears input
            HomeScreen.messageInput.setEnabled(true);
            HomeScreen.messageInput.setText("");

            // Shows the message send menu and hides sending text
            HomeScreen.sendMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HomeScreen.sendingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Clears message variable
            message = "";
            attachment = null;

            try 
            {                   
                // Reloads the message list
                messageFriendId = "";
                currentInstance.loadMessageList(true);
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                currentInstance.loadingScreen.open("Error", "Try again later!", true, "Ok", currentInstance);
            }

            // Checks if the message is sending
            isMessageSending = false;
            break;
...
...
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Broadcast Receiver instead of a handler to refresh your ui.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

```
private BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("UPDATE")) {
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("output");
            updateUI(text);
        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals("RESTART")) {
            //other stuff
            Board.this.startService(i);
        }
    }
};

//from Service
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("UPDATE");
                intent.putExtra("output",modifiedSentence);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);


//onStart
LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("UPDATE");
    filter.addAction("RESTART");
    bManager.registerReceiver(bReceiver, filter);

//onPause
LocalBroadcastManager bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    bManager.unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
```

Comment: Will the broadcast receiver definitely work? I use handlers in the app to update the UI in all of the other activities so I'm trying to keep it the same all around!

Comment: Yes, I've made several apps using services which update the ui with broadcast receiver. Handlers are better suited for worker threads in your activity. Services are totally separate from your activity though.